# Name of this terrifying, distorted guitar-like sound?

Tags: sound-effects

I've been looking on SoundEffectsWiki for the name of this certain sound that always creeped me out as a kid. It sounds like a very detuned electric guitar with heavy feedback, and the sound first rises in pitch before a stop drop.

As a kid, I remember hearing it in more places than one. You can hear it used in The Hobbit (2003) at exactly 3:14:17 in this video.

Any help is appreciated! I'd love to know which sound library it comes from too.

Cheers!

Comment: Sounds more like a brass section than a guitar. What makes you think it came as-is from a sample library? It's a fairly standard thriller/horror scoring structure. The style is known as [Aleatoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleatoric_music)

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that it's a brass section, I can't match the timbre. I think it's from a library since I remember hearing it in more places than one.

Comment: I would have to agree with @Tetsujin - this is definitely layered brass, *not* guitar.

Comment: That's some impressive brass sound design, then. Fooled me! Thanks a ton for your help, guys.